# How to set up a separate LAMP stack for a specific interface/subnet on Debian?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, openvpn, lamp

I'd like to expose one LAMP stack (actually a http root and a MySQL database) to the Internet and another to OpenVPN tunneling interface (192.168...) to make all the web-based management tools and intranet web applications only available over VPN. Can you direct me a bit on how to acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

You could bind Apache to the tunnel interface.  Having any part of the server on the Internet substantially increases the risk and you would not be able to consider the tunnel fully secured.